# Symfony 3.4 ChoiceType dynamically add choices

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I need your help with a little issue with Symfony 3.4 forms.

The idea is that I have a Data entity which assigned to a Trip entity (the Trip table is the parent of the Data table which has a column trip_id references Trip.id). And of course trips are submitted with a form and saved in the database.

But when I want to add a data I want also to added the trip_id.
I tried this because I found it logical but it seems at the end that its just an illusion:

```
$formBuilder->add('trip', ChoiceType::class, [
            'choices' => [
                foreach ($trips in trip){
                    "$trip->getName()" => "$trip->getId()"
                }
            ]
        ])
```

I think you got the idea. I want to retrieve the trips from the database and dynamically add them to the ChoiceType, exactly like we do in a normal PHP:

```
<form action="#" method..>
    <select>
       <?php foreach ($trips as $trip){
       '<option value='".$trip->getId().'">'.$trip->getName().'</option>
       }?>
    </select>
</form>
```

Comment: You can create the array of trips outside of `$formBuilder` and pass that array to `choices`

Comment: That's the weirdest thing I have ever seen Salim :D

Comment: hahahaha xD i admet that @emix xD but well I found it logical at the begening till i hit my head and say come on its an array :P

Comment: @RazvanBalosin Thank you! yeah thats it, gona try it now, or maybe i need to try the EntityType before as described in the first anwser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an EntityType field for that

https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html

Comment: Thats it! Thank you! But i have a little question, after i do form->handleRequest i get an object within the getData method right?

Comment: Yep, you can have `$form->getData();` after the form was submited